# Windows 7 - delay with offline network drives

Tags: windows-7, networking, nas, samba

I have a desktop running Win 7 Pro 64. I have an NAS server (Debian 10) with HDDs shared via Samba. Everything works as expected when the NAS server is on but if it is offline then I get lots of delays in Windows, for example, when opening programs or right-clicking in Explorer. I suspect that whenever I do anything Windows is looking for the missing network drives but I cannot figure out why or what to do to fix the problem.

EDIT: To be clear, no network drives are mapped (they were but now unmapped). Accessing the network drives works perfectly fine, no problems reading or writing. The problem is that when the network drives are offline then almost everything I do on Windows is delayed by 60-120 seconds (opening Solitaire or right-clicking a file or directory, etc.). I have another Win7 machine on the same LAN and it doesn't have the problem so it is clearly a configuration issue of some kind. But, I don't know what the issue is to fix it!

UPDATE: Using cleanboot I narrowed down the problem to one service: Network Store Interface Service. Disabling that eliminates 99% of my slowness issues BUT also disables all network access. Uninstalled the network adopter (based on advice to solve problems with that service) but the problem reappears when new adopter driver is installed. Could use help on how to "clean" the NSI settings as I'm guessing that is my problem.

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you still running Windows 7?

Comment: Sounds like a format may be in order. Have you tried removing the shares temporarily to see if this behavior stops? It's probably a good time to upgrade the OS if I'm being totally honest... Using win-7 at this point is playing with fire.

Comment: Try this. Delete the shares so nothing is mapped. Run TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer    . Then remap the shares (proper mapping - net use z: \\device\folder   and then check speed.

Comment: @Keltan - Hate Win10 GUI but it doesn't seem to want to run on my computer, every update breaks audio and on my laptop it stops the battery from working.

Comment: @John - There are no mapped drives. I already deleted them in trying to troubleshoot. To be clear, in Linux the drives are shared and can be accessed via Windows Exploter WHEN THE NAS IS ONLINE.

Comment: I asked because my Windows 7 VM found my Windows 10 host instantly by NET USE T: \\.....    Make sure about SMBV1 / 2 and if all is the same there

Comment: @John - we might be talking at cross purposes here. I have no problem accessing the shared drives - access is no problem. The problem is when the drives are offline and unavailable. Much of what I do involves a 60-120 second delay. I suspect the reason is that in the background Windows is trying to access the offline LAN drives and has to wait for a timeout because the drives are not available.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  Don't understand - there are no "shares" on Win7 machine to remove.

Comment: How Are you using the shares in the first place when you map them? Are you mapping from DNS name? Or are you mapping from the server ip address? I.e \\my-server\my-share\ vs. \\192.168.1.200\my-share\ ?? I'm assuming you have tried totally uninstalling the NIC, then reinstalling with latest manufacturer drivers...

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I don't understand your questions. There are no shares and no mappings on Windows. I have a Linux machine called "NAS" set up at 192.168.1.99 on my LAN. I can use either to access files from Windows in Explorer. No drives are mapped, I access server drives via the name or IP directly in Explorer without any problems ever. [Edited title as it might have been confusing you.]

Comment: Did you follow johns instructions to reset the tcpip stack in the OS?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart  Yes, I did reset the TCPIP stack. Made no difference, which is not a surprise if I understand what the reset does.